# Multiple Cron Jobs in 1 file (cPanel)

Tags: php, api, cron

Im using worldweatheronline api for current weather temp for 150 cities

I need to update the temperature every 1 hour for every 150 cities,

My links to update this are like this

```
mydomain.com/update/current.php?city=1
mydomain.com/update/current.php?city=2
...
mydomain.com/update/current.php?city=150
```

I think adding 150 cronjobs is not a good idea, also the limit for api calls is 3 calls for every second, so this can be a problem too.

I need your help on this, thank you.

Comment: distribute the cron jobs every time consecutively.. so it wont pull all requests at the same time. for every minute or half a minute perhaps try 2-3 requests.. it's all about scheduling your cron at different intervals. the important thing is it updates every 1 hour, right?

Comment: If you say 'do my job please', you study nothing this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the `current.php` is specific for cron job. (i think,it's a good idea to seperate cron jobs program from others). just call it without parameter and do a loop for different `$city` inside the PHP program

Comment: yes is specific file for cron job, i like this idea but will be any problem with php limits, because this job can take more than 2 minutes to be completed?

Comment: Then save `$city` in a table column like `cron_city` and initiate it to 1. every time you run the `current.php`. start your loop from `cron_city` for just 50 cities (for example, based on time to be complete) until you reach 150, then initialize it to 1 and so on...

Comment: ok thank you for your time, i like this idea and i think i can do it works

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
#!/bin/bash

for X in 1 .. 150
do
    mydomain.com/update/current.php?city=$X
done
```

For the cron job

Comment: with this jobs will run consecutively or concurrently?

Comment: anyway to limit 3 jobs in 1 second?

Comment: @user2361987 - It will do the 150 jobs sequentially.